# How to mount folder for custom docker image on Azure App Service Linux

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, dockerfile

When i create web app on azure and i need to deploy my code - i can just put files to **/site/wwwroot** folder.

But when i try to build custom docker image i dont understand how to have a same behavior. On the official image - https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/php/blob/master/7.0.6-apache/Dockerfile, i take a look code:

```
ln -s /home/site/wwwroot /var/www/html
```

but it is not work for my (i dont understand why).

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.0.6-apache
RUN ln -s /home/site/wwwroot /var/www/html
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Comment: You need to keep the files in current context and COPY then using the COPY command in Dockerfile. like `COPY mysite /var/www/html` and no need for `ln -s` statement as such

Comment: @TarunLalwani I want to deploy my code by copying files to `/home/site/wwwroot` (by FT like default behavior). If i will use `COPY` - i need to build my image after each code editing.

Comment: Is the folder `/home/site/wwwroot` on your machine? If yes then this would only work through volumes. `docker run -v /home/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html imageid`

Comment: @TarunLalwani, i use Azure App Service on Linux, i am not directly running `run` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app settings look for this setting: WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE . Make sure this is set to true. By default storage mounting is turned off for "Web App for Containers" (Instances where you bring your own container). This is to prevent app restarts for things like storage failover if you're not using storage. If you include this setting and set it to true it'll mount just like our official images do. We're working on making this more transparent and settable in a way other than through an app setting.

[Image of App Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H39ug.png)

Comment: Thank you, but it dont help. What i do: 1. create web app on linux; 2. use appsvc/php; 3. change WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE to true; 4. restart web app.

Comment: Web app for test - http://appsvc-test.azurewebsites.net/. For create that i was use steps above.